# Swiftui - Delete List row

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to delete a list's row.

I have followed Apple's official SwiftUI tutorials to build this part of my App. You can download SwiftUI **Essentials - Handling User Input** from https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input if you wish so.

---

I am using `onDelete` modifier to delete rows.

```
        ForEach(filteredLandmarks) { landmark in
            NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
            }
        }
        .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
            for index in indexSet {
                self.modelData.landmarks.remove(at: index)
            }
        })
```

It works as long as you do not navigate to `LandmarkDetail` view. If you do so, the app crushes due to `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. It is because as you see in the following code, `firstIndex` is forced unwrapped.

```
struct LandmarkDetail: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    
    var landmark: Landmark

    var landmarkIndex: Int {
        modelData.landmarks.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == landmark.id })!
    }

    var body: some View {
      FavoriteButton(isSet: $modelData.landmarks[landmarkIndex].isFavorite)
    }
}
```

---

I can not figure how to allow editing `Landmark` in `LandmarkDetail` and also be able to delete it.

---

#### Info

In order to test, Tap on a row to  navigate to `LandmarkDetail` and then navigate back to `LandmarkList`. Then delete the row that you just tapped on.

Comment: Are you trying to view an object that has been deleted?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No.I am trying to delete an object that just has been viewed.  I have added more info.

Comment: So why not just don't force unwrap the value returned by firstIndex?

Comment: @DanielT. Can you access an array's object with optional int, for example in `FavoriteButton(isSet: $modelData.landmarks[landmarkIndex].isFavorite)` ?

Comment: The object doesn't exist anymore so why would you think you _can_ access it?

Comment: And when does it crash? After the latest edit it isn't clear anymore.

Comment: It's crazy that the LandmarkDetail's body is computed when it isn't even on screen anymore

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are removing an index from `modelData`, but you are sending `landmark` object from `filteredLandmarks` variable to `LandmarkDetail` view (the object is still available in `filteredLandmarks`). So, inside LandmarkDetail view, the 'modelData' is not contain the 'landmark' variable you provided.

In `LandmarkDetail` view:

```
var landmarkIndex: Int {
    guard let index = modelData.landmarks.firstIndex(where: { return $0.id == landmark.id }) else {
        return 0
    }
    return index
}
```

OR,

You can try to find out a solution to remove the exact row index from `filteredLandmarks` variable.